# $(X_1, Y_1), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n)$ are iid random pairs, does it mean $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Questions are as shown in title. $(X_1, Y_1), \ldots, (X_n, Y_n)$ are iid random pairs, does it mean $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are iid?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Comment: and identically distributed.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.